# Variance of the distribution of difference scores

Tags: variance

Assume we have two dependent populations with variances $\sigma^2_{a}$ and $\sigma^2_{b}$ and we want to consider the distribution of difference scores for all dependent pairs. Typically the variance of the distribution of difference scores is defined as $\sigma^2_{D}$ = $\sigma^2_{a}$+$\sigma^2_{b}$-2cov(a,b).

But an equivalent form seems to be $\sigma^2_{D}$ = 2($\sigma^2_{a}$+$\sigma^2_{b}$-2$\sigma^2_{s}$), where $\sigma^2_{s}$ is the variance of the distribution of mean scores for the dependent pairs; i.e., the distribution of $(a_{i} + b_{i} )/2$.

Can you point me to a proof that this is the case?

Comment: You have the proof right there in your question.You have \begin{align}var(A-B) &= var(A) + var(B) - 2cov(A,B)\\var(A+B) &= var(A) + var(B) + 2cov(A,B)\end{align} giving that $$var(A-B) = 2var(A)+2var(B) - var(A+B).$$ Now consider that $var(A+B) = 4var(\frac{A+B}{2})$ and substitute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment reposted an answer so that this question doesn't get thrown up repeatedly as an Unanswered Question....

You have the proof right there in your question. You have 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{var}(A+B) &= \operatorname{var}(A)+\operatorname{var}(B) + 2\operatorname{cov}(A,B)\\
\operatorname{var}(A-B) &= \operatorname{var}(A)+\operatorname{var}(B) - 2\operatorname{cov}(A,B)
\end{align}
from which it follows that
$$\operatorname{var}(A-B) = 2\operatorname{var}(A)+2\operatorname{var}(B) - \operatorname{var}(A+B).$$
But, $\operatorname{var}(A+B) = 4\operatorname{var}\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$ giving that
$$\operatorname{var}(A-B) = 2
\left(\operatorname{var}(A)+\operatorname{var}(B) - 2\operatorname{var}\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\right).$$